# i can't get getPrefix() or getNamespacePrefix() to work on android

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I got an issue with my code with XmlPullParser and don't know if this is just me or a bug.

i simply parse a xml file using xmlpullparser (like follow):

```
   XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
         xpp = c.getResources().getXml(id);
         int quantity = 0;
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                  Log.d("al","Start tag "+xpp.getPrefix());
            }
            xpp.next();
        }
```

and the program don't work , it say RuntimeException , getPrefix not supported .
i found nothing about that.
am i doing something wrong ?

(i'm using api 7 and anddev site say it's here since api 1)

Comment: The code looks strange. You are asking for an XmlPullParser from the factory, and then overwriting it with an XmlPullParser from your Resources.  Which one do you want to use?

Comment: The one from ressource. I forgot to delete the one from factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the

```
xpp = c.getResources().getXml(id);
```

like Robby said , getPrefix() wasn't implemented

instead of that ,i do :

```
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(c.getResources().openRawResource(id));
xpp.setInput(isr);
```

can it be because my factory is Nampespace aware and the getResources().getXml() return a XmlRessourceParser that don't care of namespace ?

Answer (score 0):

`XmlPullParser` is an interface so you must be getting some default `XmlPullParser` implementation, and that implementation's `getPrefix()` method is throwing the exception because `getPrefix()` isn't implemented.